# How do I fix a "failed to list contents of container" error?

Tags: juju

I'm running Juju in the Windows 7 OS.  When running `juju bootstrap`, the following error occurred:

```
C:\Users\t00106584>juju bootstrap
error: failed to list contents of container: juju-6d8590a4634bc451763da9a8a93ad351
caused by: authentication failed
caused by: failed executing the request https://172.1 67.10.10:5000/v2.0//tokens
caused by: Post https://172.1 67.10.10:5000/v2.0//tokens: local error: record overflow
```

I modified the file: environments.yaml

and changed `auth-url: https://172.167.10.10:5000/v2.0/` to `auth-url: http://172.167.10.10:5000/v2.0/`

The error is gone, but another error appears:**

```
C:\Users\t00106584>juju bootstrap
error: failed to list contents of container: juju-6d8590a4634bc451763da9a8a93ad351
caused by: cannot create service URLs
caused by: the configured region "RegionOne" does not allow access to all required services, namely: compute, object-store
access to these services is missing: object-store
```

---------------environments.yaml---------------

```
default: openstack

environments:
  openstack:
    type: openstack
    admin-secret: 004cfb82cfd545035fab61fa2b603f96
    control-bucket: juju-6d8590a4634bc451763da9a8a93ad351
    auth-url: http://172.167.10.10:5000/v2.0/
    auth-mode: userpass
    username: admin
    password: RandomPassWord
    tenant-name: admin
    region: RegionOne
```

Answer (score 1):

Does your OpenStack installation have an object store? You need swift in order to use Juju with OpenStack as Juju uses it to cache items there. That error means you don't have an object store that's available within Keystone